# How to call remote methods with json-RPC and get the return response in Android

Tags: android, json, web-services

There is a webservice that receive remote calls on a link in this form http://example.com/webservicename.fga

I have tried to use json to make the login call but I don't get any answer.
I must get the response of the webservice that should return a sessionKey and an id

The server-side method startSession on the webservice is

```
@Webservice(paramNames = {"email", "password", "stayLogged", "idClient"},
public Response startSession(String email, String password, Boolean stayLogged, String idClient) throws Exception {
    boolean rC = stayLogged != null && stayLogged.booleanValue();
    UserService us = new UserService();
    User u = us.getUsersernamePassword(email, password);
    if (u == null || u.getActive() != null && !u.getActive().booleanValue()) {
        return ErrorResponse.getAccessDenied(id, logger);
    }
    InfoSession is = null;
    String newKey = null;
    while (newKey == null) {
        newKey = UserService.md5(Math.random() + " " + new Date().getTime());
        if (SessionManager.get(newKey) != null) {
            newKey = null;
        } else {
            is = new InfoSession(u, rC, newKey);
            if (idClient != null && idClient.toUpperCase().equals("ANDROID")) {
                is.setClient("ANDROID");
            }
            SessionManager.add(newKey, is);
        }
    }
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "New session started: " + newKey + " - User: " + u.getEmail());
    return new Response(new InfoSessionJson(newKey, is), null, id);
}
```

I have tried to access it using this client-side code

```
static final String BASE_URI="http://example.com/webservicename.fga"

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(BASE_URI); 

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); 
String email="testmail@test.it";
String emailRic="email"+" "+"\""+email+"\"";
String password="1234";
String passwordRic="password"+" "+"\""+password+"\"";
String stayLogged="1";
String stayLoggedRic="stayLogged"+" "+"\""+stayLogged+"\"";
String idClient="ANDROID";
String idClientRic="idClient"+" "+"\""+idClient+"\"";

try {
    List<String> accessParameters=new ArrayList<String>();
    accessParameters.add(emailRic);
    accessParameters.add(passwordRic);
    accessParameters.add(stayLoggedRic);
    accessParameters.add(idClientRic);

    String parameterS=accessParameters.toString();
    String RPCx=BASE_URI+"{\"method\":\""+"startSession"+"\", \"accessParameters\":";
    RPCx+=parameterS;
    RPCx+=", \"id\":1}";
    String RPCString=RPCx.toString();


    JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray(); 
    postjson.put(RPCString); 
    httppost.setHeader("RPCString",RPCString.toString());
    httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",postjson); 
    System.out.print(RPCString); 
    HttpResponse response = mClient.execute(httppost); 

    if(response != null){
        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println("the answer is:\n"+sb);
        String line = null;

    try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
   // text = sb.toString();
    }
   // tv.setText(text);

}catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

**But with no success.**

Certainly there is something wrong in my client-side code (the webservice works fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is wrong,

**I cannot** send a whole string as json request in this way

```
String RPCx=BASE_URI+"{\"method\":\""+"startSession"+"\", \"accessParameters\":";
```

I should create a JSONObject with method attribute and a nested  JSONArray for parameters, done this I must send the root  JSONObject to the server.